# Confused about trancend ssd life indicator

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I resently buy Trancend 240 GB MLC SSD Drive(TS256GSSD340K). Install Windows 7 on it and all be perfect. Until i start see that health indicator in propietary program SSD Scope not 100% anymore. And this after few month of usage. Page file are turned off (16GB RAM). Process Monitor shows that Chrome Browser frequently write data to SSD. After this i`m remove chrome from this machine, but this didn't help. Health indicator lose aprox. 1% in one weak on propietary program and dont lose any in SSD Life Lite program.
[image]

Comment: As a Solid State Drive it determines this by how many writes occur. SSDs are supposed to last up to 20 Years before Failing although you will probably get a new drive before the drive even thinks about failing. That or a new Computer.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right info? TS256GSSD340K seems to be a 256 GB drive.

Comment: Yes! But in explorer it show like has 238Gb... maybe trim do that...

Comment: 240GB drive will be shown as a 223GB drive, because Windows actually shows the size in binary unit (KiB, MiB, GiB...). Also the IDEMA formula, if you want to be precise: http://superuser.com/a/1037393/554702 So 256060514304 / (1024^3) = 238.47"GB". "TRIM" doesn't trim your drive like your gardener...

Comment: This is good, but i still dont like have 79 % health after 3 month of usage!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get utility that expose all S.M.A.R.T. attibutes to you, so that you can keep track of them and see if there is any particular attribute that keep increasing/decreasing suspiciously, and then research about what does that attribute reflect on your drive. Decent examples are:

HDD Guardian (which is a GUI on Windows of the decent smartmontools): http://hddguardian.codeplex.com/ https://www.smartmontools.org/

Crystal Disk Info:
http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html